# Adobe AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) HTL2HTML for components

Tags: aem

Adobe AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) HTL2HTML compile and test
(AEM 6.1 soon to be moving to 6.3)

I would like to automatically generate HTML from HTL Components
as part of the build process (using default / and custom values ) 
so I can provide additional automated testing and quality assurance.
i.e. HTML validation and Accessibility QA.

Is there a java call, or some other command line tool that could generate html snippets or pages for each of the components.
Which could be incorporated into the build process when making a call to
mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage

I have considered generating pages using selenium but I suspect that approach is slow and error prone.

Thanks for your help

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the rendered HTML on the server side using  [SlingRequestProcessor](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/engine/SlingRequestProcessor.html).

From @nateyolles [blog post](http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2015/10/get-rendered-html-for-an-aem-resource-or-component):

**Getting the HTML markup for a resource in Apache Sling.**

```
@SlingServlet(paths={"/bin/foo"})
public class SlingResourceResolutionServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    /** Service to process requests through Sling */
    @Reference
    private SlingRequestProcessor requestProcessor;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        /* The resource path to resolve. Use any selectors or extension. */
        String requestPath = "/content/myapp/us/en/index/jcr:content/myparsys/mycomponent_f93d.html";

        /* 
         * Create a fake request and fake response. The response adds a method to make the HTML accessible.
         * You need the following three files from Apache Sling:
         *
         * https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/testing/junit/scriptable/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/junit/scriptable/HttpRequest.java
         * https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/testing/junit/scriptable/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/junit/scriptable/HttpResponse.java
         * https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/testing/junit/scriptable/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/junit/scriptable/TestServletOutputStream.java
         */
        final HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(requestPath);
        final HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();

        /* Process request through Sling */
        requestProcessor.processRequest(req, resp, request.getResourceResolver());
        String html = resp.getContent();
    }
```

**Getting the HTML markup for a resource in AEM.**

```
@SlingServlet(paths={"/bin/foo"})
public class AemResourceResolutionServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    /** Service to create HTTP Servlet requests and responses */
    @Reference
    private RequestResponseFactory requestResponseFactory;

    /** Service to process requests through Sling */
    @Reference
    private SlingRequestProcessor requestProcessor;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        /* The resource path to resolve. Use any selectors or extension. */
        String requestPath = "/content/myapp/us/en/index/jcr:content/myparsys/mycomponent_f93d.html";

        /* Setup request */
        HttpServletRequest req = requestResponseFactory.createRequest("GET", requestPath);
        WCMMode.DISABLED.toRequest(req);

        /* Setup response */
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        HttpServletResponse resp = requestResponseFactory.createResponse(out);

        /* Process request through Sling */
        requestProcessor.processRequest(req, resp, request.getResourceResolver());
        String html = out.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll give it a go